# How to create menu fixed to the left corner?

Tags: html, css

I looking how to create menu like this http://www.panic.lv/en/ . Menu have to bi fixed in left corner, so menu can stay on scroll. When I use CSS from this website

```
#nav-corner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 800;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

I got this on mine website
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/443096/8c36574b9c0461dbd40f92ecb4257485

Menu isn't in top left corner, and when I downsize width he is moving i corner, but without width:100% I'm losing my corner peace. I only could solve this using top:-170, and add height for example 220px; but that is bad solution because of responsive, on smaller resolutions I'm losing my icon.

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

[image: menu]

```css
body{
  background-color: #000000;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-space {
    position: fixed;
    height: 203px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 800;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(-10deg) translate(-50px, -177px);
    padding: 43px;
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.menu-icon {
    position: fixed;
    height: 5em;
    top: 1.25em;
    left: 1.25em;
    z-index: 800;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="menu-space"></div>
 <span class="menu-icon"><img src="http://motiongiraffx.com/wp-content/themes/motiongiraffx/images/menu-icon.png" id="nav-icon" onclick="changeImage()" alt="Menu icon"></span>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

With this code you can remove  `top: -170px` i use `transform: rotate(-10deg) translate(-50px, -177px);` Instead `transform: skewY(-10deg);` And other small changes in html and css

can see here http://liveweave.com/WQZWpX

---

ok for solve problem in mobile you just need add `position: fixed;` and `width: calc(100% + 100px);` to `.responsive-menu` class

```
.responsive-menu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 900;
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
}
```

and for solve small problem follow me

. change `@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {` to `@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {` in `media-query.css`

. add this css to `media-query.css` file

```
@media (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 639px) {
  .resp-menu-space {
    height: 66px;
  }
}
```

test it

Comment: I I tried this I got icon on right place, but #nav-corner is still on same place as I showed on my screenshot. I don't know why this div doesn't want to go up i corner. :(

Comment: why right? I want my menu in top left corner? Problem is with #nav-corner div, it won't go to the top with this css. See my screenshot again to see what is the main problem, please.

Comment: All you made works for me, too. I put icon on place where I want, no problem with that, problem is with #nav-corner div that should be always in top left corner and skewY(-10deg);

Comment: can you please add more your html and css code i can't understand what you want

Comment: Ok, this is my website http://motiongiraffx.com/services/ . I you take look at my div .menu-space it have position: fixed; and top: -170px; That's only way how I made this work and I don't want to use top: -170px because it makes me problem with responsive. I tried everything to make this div fixed in left top corner but can't make it works, obvious it's possible, as I can see on Panic website, but I can't make it work in my case.

Comment: Hey, sorry I couldn't check before. It's better now, but I still have problem when I downsize resolution. For example it works fine on fullHD but when I come to, for example 1400px, menu goes in minus, still isn't fixed, if you understand me. Just try on my website.

Comment: Sorry late, I was busy,i add in answer

Comment: Thank you, but in meantime I found one more solution for this. I found property transform-origin: 0 0; and it works, too. :)